# SQLDescribeCol() returns SQL_VARCHAR for BINARY, BLOB, WCHAR, DECIMAL

Tags: sqlite, odbc, unixodbc

Using the [ODBC driver for SQLite](https://github.com/softace/sqliteodbc) under unixodbc, I'm often getting unhelpful results back from SQLDescribeCol.

For instance, in a table created with:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    `value` BINARY(3) NOT NULL
)
```

I do the simple parameter-less ODBC query:

```
SELECT value FROM `test_table`
```

Which gives back a result set with one column, where my C code says something along the lines of:

```
SQLWCHAR title[COLUMN_TITLE_SIZE];
SQLSMALLINT title_length;
SQLSMALLINT sql_type;  
SQLULEN column_size;
SQLSMALLINT precision;  
SQLSMALLINT nullable;

SQLRETURN rc = SQLDescribeColW(
    hstmt,
    column_index,  // 1 in this case
    &title[0],
    COLUMN_TITLE_SIZE,
    &title_length,
    &sql_type,
    &column_size,
    &precision,
    &nullable
);
```

Despite the BINARY in the table definition, it comes back with `sql_type == SQL_VARCHAR`.  This problem doesn't exist for some types...like integers or times/dates, SQL_BIT, or most floating point numbers.  But the same thing happens with BLOB columns, NCHAR columns, and DECIMAL in particular.

I'm trying to automatically pick the right type for values coming back from columns in a language binding, and so it's important to distinguish this type.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a bug (or unimplemented feature) in the SQLite unixodbc driver.  It seems that the problem is that for any type that it has to `malloc()` an arbitrary buffer, its internal typing is the same.

Here is a suggested workaround: The driver actually does know the string name of the type of the column...and you can get it with [SQLColAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlcolattribute-function?view=sql-server-ver15) by passing it `SQL_DESC_TYPE_NAME`.

```
char type_name[100];  // Note: `typename` is a C++ keyword
SQLSMALLINT type_name_len;
rc = SQLColAttribute(  // or SQLColAttributeW--see NOTE below
    hstmt,  // StatementHandle
    column_index,  // ColumnNumber
    SQL_DESC_TYPE_NAME,  // FieldIdentifier, see SQL_DESC_XXX list
    &type_name,  // CharacterAttributePtr
    100,  // BufferLength
    &type_name_len,  // StringLengthPtr
    nullptr  // NumericAttributePtr, not needed w/string attribute
);
```

**NOTE: The above worked on unixodbc.  But reports came back that the Windows SQLite driver was giving back a wide character string as the type_name, even though `SQLColAttribute` was called and not `SQLColAttributeW`.  If anyone has more to say on that, please chime in.**

This `type_name` will come back and give you the distinction such as BINARY, and so if you look for patterns of the types you want in that you can generate the SQL_BINARY etc. types you want.

*Note: There is code in the driver to do [mappings of strings to SQL_TYPEs](https://github.com/softace/sqliteodbc/blob/7f9e7025382f1e09724b33fef46906e3e6e1cadf/sqlite3odbc.c#L2176).  But it doesn't seem to use this in SELECTs, only on INSERTs.*

Comment: `SqlColAttribute` is a simple `#define` to either `SqlColAttributeW` or `SqlColAttributeA`, where the W-function is for the "Unicode" character set (using wstring / SQLWCHAR), while the A-function is for the "Multi-Byte character set" (using strind / SQLCHAR). The W-functions are usually enabled if `UNICODE` is defined. 
This works like that for (almost) all windows functions, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings for the generic case, or here for odbc: https://github.com/microsoft/ODBC-Specification/blob/master/Windows/inc/sqlucode.h

Comment: @erg Hmmm... oh.  So is SqlColAttributeA guaranteed to be defined on unix odbc?  I actually compile on Linux not Windows, but [this patch](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c/commit/438f4aa08edf2edf1e1aa03d7ff1dabc1f6a2f05#diff-2eef67ba3a28651b52e60f00b96f2607R797) made a difference for the Windows user... which suggests perhaps that UNICODE is defined, hence "SqlColAttribute" was getting the W version, I guess...

Comment: I'm (mostly) on windows and would never code directly against any of the 'A' or 'W' versions, it just feels wrong. Therefore I would also not rely on UnixOdbc defining any 'A' variant. You probably can rely on a A function being present on windows and do something ugly as `#ifdef WIN32 .. #endif`. Some time ago I've written a cross-platform odbc wrapper for one of our projects, where I just used std::string (utf-8 encoded) inside everywhere, and wherever it comes to the windows API boundaries I convert from utf-8 to wstring holding unicode: https://exodbc.elisium.ch/trac

Comment: @erg Thanks for the insight... guess I think I will just stick to the W versions for now, because it seems that in tests thus far that is what has worked most consistently (e.g. there is no confusion, the W APIs are always wide characters).